# Kafka Connect writes not full timestamp from Oracle DB

Tags: oracle, jdbc, apache-kafka, timestamp, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using Kafka Connect with oracle database and jdbc connector. When Kafka Connect read from database timestamp and write it in the topic, it writes only day, month and year and writes time by zeros (for example: 1598227200000). Help me, please. How to write in a topic full timestamp?

Comment: Sounds like it is handling a `DATE` as a real `DATE`, not as a `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: In DB timestamp column is TIMESTAMP(0). Do you know how to solve this problem?